# Load more data on Scroll View ends

Tags: android

i want to load more data in a fragment when scroll View reaches end..
My layout has Scroll view with a Linear Layout i am creating Tex view and button dynamically..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="@drawable/background">

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtv"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/booktitle" />
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollViewid"
android:layout_below="@+id/txtv">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearlayoutid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use either a `recyclerview` or `listview` for that, scrollview is not meant for that refer this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html and run this sample app to understand it better http://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/index.html since recyclerview is new i recommend you use that